# What happens when I don't include a header file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In xcode, when I add a new objective-c file, there's a checkbox where it says something like "Add header file".  In what condition should I untick that box and what would it do if I did?

Comment: Observe both cases. What is different?

Comment: Only the objective-c file is created.  But what I mean is that why would you even want to create just the objective-c file without a header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the checkbox if you will need a different .m or .c file to be able to access symbols defined in the .m file you're creating. Those symbols will need the be declared in the .h file created for you when you check the checkbox. For example, a class declaration used in other files would belong in your header file.

Answer (score 3):

You can skip the header file for any object file that does not need to separately declare any of its symbols.

This is fairly common in CLI-based applications. The “C runtime” (e.g. `crt1.o`) knows how to call `main`, so you can usually omit a header file for the `.c` file that defines your `main` function (assuming your application has only a single source file or none of the other source files reference symbols that are defined in the same file as `main`).

The `main.m` file from the [UDPEcho sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UDPEcho/Introduction/Intro.html) is an example of an Objective C file that does not need a `.h` file.

Most of the “modules” in Cocoa-based applications require a header file because they will need to export at least one symbol to some other bit of your application. Sometimes you need to send a message to an instance of a class defined in another file, sometimes *Interface Builder* (or whatever) needs to know which actions and outlets are available in your classes, et cetera. The easiest way to make this information available is via a header file.